# Integrating Elasticsearch with MongoDb and Springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a Springboot application with mongodb as database. I need some reference or guidance to integrate elasticsearch for search purposes. I have seen some resources saying I need to replicate mongodb for that but some don't have that.
Any reference to this would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sam that is a very broad question, there are many ways of using combinations of MongoDB and syncing data to elasticsearch. Do you do it real time , or in batches or do you send data both ways from the applications. The spectrum of this is way too broad for a single question/answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.